# Jenkins workflow job: limit where it can run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins workflow jobs that start the same job with different parameters, namely, the branch they build. The latter job builds the project on several platforms. The "head" job, that is the worklflow job may start on different machines. Also, there are two linux machines in the setup.

And sometimes it so happens that one of them (say, master) starts on one of the linux machines, and the other one starts on the other. Both of them have to build a target on a linux machine, and since both of them are busy, both jobs stall.

With usual jobs, one can limit where they can run, however, I couldn't find how to limit where a workflow job can run. Obviously, it should be done using the groovy script, but it escapes me how exactly.

Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a Jenkinsfile to do it globally (this is telling jenkins the entire pipeline must be run on a slave with these three labels):

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker && git && rbenv' }
  stages {
    stage('commit_stage') {
      steps {
        echo 'building stuff'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can also select a certain slave or certain capabilities via the `node` step for any stage or part of a stage:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker && git && rbenv' }
  stages {
    stage('commit_stage') {
      steps {
        // this overrides the top-level agent requirements
        node('linux_with_zsh') {
          echo 'building stuff'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```